# How to add 2 buttons in Panel to collapse/expand all groups in a grid in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a panel and inside of it I have a grid, so my question is how to have 2 buttons to **collapse/expand** all groups in a grid? I'm still new to ExtJs.

Here's the code that I'm using. It works just fine.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['name', 'seniority', 'department'],
groupField: 'department',
data: [
    { name: 'Michael Scott', seniority: 7, department: 'Management' },
    { name: 'Dwight Schrute', seniority: 2, department: 'Sales' },
    { name: 'Jim Halpert', seniority: 3, department: 'Sales' },
    { name: 'Kevin Malone', seniority: 4, department: 'Accounting' },
    { name: 'Angela Martin', seniority: 5, department: 'Accounting' }
]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title: 'Employees',
store: store,
columns: [
    { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Seniority', dataIndex: 'seniority', flex: 1 }
],
features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Maybe using **dockedItem** in the Panel will be the way I want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For buttons, I guess you would use a toolbar on your grid:

```
tbar:[{
    iconCls:'x-fa fa-plus-square',
    handler:function(btn) {
        btn.up('grid').getView().findFeature("grouping").expandAll();
    }
},{
    iconCls:'x-fa fa-minus-square',
    handler:function(btn) {
        btn.up('grid').getView().findFeature("grouping").collapseAll();
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

## shortcut

you can directly set the collapsible property attributes of a grid as per your requirement.